# How create a loop in R with non-sequential order of vector

Tags: r, loops, vector

I need to create a loop in R but my vector is not sequential. For example,

```
for (a in  1:20){
}
```

I need to exclude a=19 from the vector and jump to a=20.
I really appreciate any help you can provide. Thank you so much in advance for devoting time and energy.

Comment: "Just do it"  :-)

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
for (a in  c(1:18, 20)){}
```

Comment: I'm amazed that the best, and most straightforward, answer is supplied by the "newbie" .    If I may suggest,  you could add a sentence or two explaining that `myindices <-  c({any  positive integers you want}); for(j in myindices){do_stuff}`  always works.

Answer (score 3):

Other approaches besides those already shown are:

```
for (i in (1:20)[-19]) {}
```

and

```
for (i in seq_along(1:20)[-19]) {}
```

Note that `seq_along()` handles empty vectors better.

Comment: That's cute but kind of silly.

Comment: I don't think so. The answer in which you direclty select the indexes you want is more straightforward but also more complicated in cases where you have a lot of 'breakpoints'. For example, imagine you're trying to select all indexes between 1 and 20 except 3, 6, 11 and 14; you will have to write something like `c(1, 2, 4, 5, 7:10, 12, 13, 15:20)`. Or, instead, you could just write `(1:20)[-c(3, 6, 11, 14)]`. IMHO the latter is more intuitive.

Comment: Understood;  I'd still prefer to create the index vector as an object.  Further, your approach won't work for repeated values.

Comment: Yes. The case of repeated values was addressed by @ThomasIsCoding before I wrote this. My answer and his (the second one) can be combined.

Answer (score 2):

Use `setdiff` (if you don't have duplicates)

```
for (a in setdiff(1:20, 19)) {}
```

Otherwise, you can try something like

```
x <- rep(1:20, 2)
for (a in x[!x %in% c(18,19)]) {}
```

or

```
for (a in x) {
   if (!a %in% c(18,19)) {
   }
}
```

Comment: That works in this example, but if the original set had repetitions, it wouldn't.  E.g. `setdiff(c(1:5, 1:5), 4)` doesn't give `c(1:3, 5, 1:3, 5)` as might be desired.

Comment: @user2554330 yes, that's good point. see my update according to your feedback

Comment: Again, cute but a lot of work where just invoking the known vector of indices will work.

Answer (score 2):

```r
# setdiff but duplicates are kept
setdiff2 <- function(x, y){
  x[match(x, y, 0L) == 0L]
}

for (i in setdiff2(1:20, 19L)){
 print(paste("HI!", i))
}
#> [1] "HI! 1"
#> [1] "HI! 2"
#> [1] "HI! 3"
#> [1] "HI! 4"
#> [1] "HI! 5"
#> [1] "HI! 6"
#> [1] "HI! 7"
#> [1] "HI! 8"
#> [1] "HI! 9"
#> [1] "HI! 10"
#> [1] "HI! 11"
#> [1] "HI! 12"
#> [1] "HI! 13"
#> [1] "HI! 14"
#> [1] "HI! 15"
#> [1] "HI! 16"
#> [1] "HI! 17"
#> [1] "HI! 18"
#> [1] "HI! 20"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>